# How to refresh/reload angular 2 application without using window.location.reload()?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to refresh/reload angular application without using window.location.reload()?

- I want to do this after logout login.
- I am just trying to load the initial root component, which usually get loaded while app bootstraps. The initial root component will take care of the preparations that the app required. nav.setRoot didn't work as the app is behaving little strange in few aspects.

window.location.reload() works but, its taking so much time.

Comment: It is not recommended in angular application as they are SPA so reloading website forcefully is against rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the proper way of doing initialization. What I can recommend you to

1. Create a service for putting your initialization code.
2. Then when login/logout send the user the proper route and use angular `route resolve` concept to do the initialization.
3. the best place to do handle app initialization is via `provide: APP_INITIALIZER`

If you share your code snippet then I it will helpful for me imagine what you actually want to do and where and why you are getting problem

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.reload()` doesn't reload "the app", just the HTML.

And the whole point of Angular is data binding. To change what the user sees on the screen, you should change your `$scope` (or `$rootscope`) variables.

Comment: This is an angular question, despite the initial wrong tags.

Comment: `...doesn't reload "the app", just the HTML.`  you mean only component not whole app right? are you sure?

Comment: I mean that it is pure JavaScript, which manipulates the DOM. The DOM is not the app.